# Acessing jetpack from class outside a fragment or activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using a recylerview which uses an adapater class and a itemViewHolder class that are declared in other files. How can I use jetpack navigation from inside a class that isn't a fragment or activity?

Tried to pass the fragment on to the adapter but received a detached fragment error.

Comment: I assume that you want to navigate based on user interactions with `RecyclerView` items (e.g., clicks). If so, raise an event from the item that the fragment observes. That could be something direct (e.g., item calls a callback function), or it could be by way of a viewmodel (item tells the viewmodel about the click, then the viewmodel updates some state that reflects the fact that we need to navigate).

Answer (score 0):

Yes @CommonsWare, I was trying to catch a click of an user on a recyclerview item.

In the MainActivityViewModel I implemented the action to be binded to the each item in recyclerview:

```
class MainActivityViewModel() : ViewModel() {

companion object {
    private val TAG: String = MainActivityViewModel::class.java.simpleName
}

var airlinesList = mutableListOf<AirlineItemViewModel>()
var adapter: AirlinesAdapter = AirlinesAdapter(airlinesList)

//api communication
val flightRadarRepository = FlightRadarRepository()

fun load(navController: WeakReference<NavController>) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //Airlines list
        try {
            val result = flightRadarRepository.flightRadarRequestsInterface.getAirlinesList()
            val resultFiltered =
                result.rows.filter { airline -> airline.name.startsWith("T") }
            resultFiltered.forEach {
                airlinesList.add(
                    AirlineItemViewModel(
                        null,
                        it.name,
                        it.code,
                        it.icao
                    ) { icao, name ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on $icao $name")
                        val navController = navController.get() ?: return@AirlineItemViewModel
                        val action =
                            StartFragmentDirections.actionStartFragmentToAirlinesFragment(
                                icao,
                                name
                            )
                        navController.navigate(action)
                    })
            }

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        } catch (error: Throwable) {
            Log.e(MainActivityViewModel.TAG, "Error", error)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class AirlineItemViewModel(
val logo: String?,
val name: String,
val code: String,
val icao: String,
val action: ((icao: String, name: String) -> Unit)?
```

) : ItemViewModel {

```
override val identifier: String = name
override val layoutId: Int = AirlineItemViewHolder.LAYOUT_ID
```

}

```
    fun bind(airlineItemViewModel: AirlineItemViewModel) {
    binding.apply {
        val context = root.context
        airlineItemViewModel.apply {
            tvName.text = name
            tvCode.text = icao
            btnDetails.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "bind -> icao: $icao, name: $name")
                action?.invoke(icao, name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```